# Work censorship

Tags: configuration, censorship, network-configuration

My work restricts web sites. Our server is located in Germany but my office is in the uk. I don't seem to be able to access the tor network. I think I need the proxy setting how do I find these

Comment: Do you use the Tor Browser? Which operating system do you use? Have you tried Tor bridges or other circumvention techniques? Please edit your answer and add those details.

Answer (score 3):

If you need Tor access for work purposes, make arrangements through management. If it's for personal use, use your own device and network connection, such as a WiFi AP. Circumventing your employer's network security might get you fired. Also, even if you succeed, IT staff could observe your activities, and that might get you fired, or worse.